# Delete first and last 'X' character from character array

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I'm trying to delete first 'w' and last 'w' from a string.
I deleted the first 'w', but couldn't delete the last one, and here is my code:

```
char str1[80], *pstr1, *pstr2;
cout << "Enter a String:\n";
gets_s(str1);
pstr1 = str1;
pstr2 = new char[strlen(str1)];
int n = strlen(str1) + 1, k = 0, i = 0;
bool s = true;
while (k < n+1)
{

    if (strncmp((pstr1 + k), "w", 1) != 0)
    {
        *(pstr2 + i) = *(pstr1 + k);
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    else if(s == true)
    {       
        k++;
        s = false;
    }
    else
    {
        *(pstr2 + i) = *(pstr1 + k);
        i++;
        k++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You call `gets_s` with wrong number of arguments. Your compiler should tell you about this.  It's important to understand and fix anything your compiler tells you about.

Comment: Another problem is that you might overflow buffer of `pstr2` if the string did not actually contain any `w` (cannot say for sure as you did not post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3):

Make your life easy and use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) with [`find_first_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of), [`find_last_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of) and [`erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase).

```
#include <string>

void erase_first_of(std::string& s, char c)
{
    auto pos = s.find_first_of(c);

    if (pos != std::string::npos)
    {
        s.erase(pos, 1);
    }
}

void erase_last_of(std::string& s, char c)
{
    auto pos = s.find_last_of(c);

    if (pos != std::string::npos)
    {
        s.erase(pos, 1);
    }
}

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "hellow, worldw\n";

    erase_first_of(s, 'w');
    erase_last_of(s, 'w');

    std::cout << s;
}
```